# Adding error in yii2 to html form

Tags: php, yii2

I want to add yii2 default error to the form that is created using only html tags:

```
<form>
   <input type="text">
</form>
```

I just shorted the form. Actually it is very long and couldn't write with

```
<?=  $form->field($model, 'model')->dropdownList([
        1 => 'item 1',
        2 => 'item 2'
    ],
    ['prompt'=>'Select Category']
    );
?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'model')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'model')->textarea(['rows' => '6']) ?>
```

even if I used costom template for each one. Because the design is very complex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  the  `$form->errorSummary($model)` eg:

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
 .......

 <?= $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

  ....
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually I need this <?= Html::error($post, 'title', ['class' => 'error']) ?> and your answer helped me find this

Comment: Sorry bro! I forgot it and I am new here